# Proper syntax in RoR for time in datetime comparison

Tags: ruby-on-rails, syntax, irb

I am trying to attribute the time param with `.to_date` to generate the proper comparison

```
Organization.find(1140).events.all(:conditions => ["time < ?", Time.now.beginning_of_day]).blank?
```

How would I do that? I tried this :

```
Organization.find(1140).events.all(:conditions => [time.to_date < ?, Time.now.beginning_of_day]).blank?
```

And that's a big fail :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
Organization.find(1140).events.all(:conditions => ["DATE(time) < ?", Date.today]).blank?
```

`DATE()` is a mysql function to parse the given value to Date format. And if you want to compare dates you should use `Date.today` instead of `Time.now.beginning_of_day`, it's much shorter and more readable.